# GDB Patching results in "Cannot access memory at address 0x

Tags: gdb, patch

I have a program that I need to patch using GDB.  The issue is there is a line of code that makes a "less than or equal test" and fails causing the program to end with a Segmentation fault.  The program is already compiled and I do not have the source so I cannot change the source code obviously.  However, using GDB, I was able to locate where the <= test is done and then I was able to locate the memory address which you can see below.

```
    (gdb) x/100i $pc
    ... removed extra lines ...
    0x7ffff7acb377:      jle    0x7ffff7acb3b1
    ....
```

All I need to do is change the test to a 'greater than or equal to' test and then the program should run fine.  The opcode for jle is 0x7e and I need to change it to 0x7d.  My assignment gives instructions on how to do this as follows:

```
    $ gdb -write -q programtomodify
    (gdb) set {unsigned char} 0x8040856f = 0x7d
    (gdb) quit
```

So I try it and get...

```
    $ gdb -write -q player
    (gdb) set {unsigned char} 0x7ffff7acb377 = 0x7d
    Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7acb377
```

I have tried various other memory addresses and no matter what I try I get the same response.  That is my only problem, I don't care if it's the wrong address or wrong opcode instruction at this point, I just want to be able to modify the memory.

I am running Linux Mint 14 via VMware Player

Thank

Comment: you can do it in any other hex editor too (but adresses work a little different in gdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7acb377`

You are trying to write to an address where some shared library resides. You can find out which library that is with `info sym 0x7ffff7acb377`.

At the time when you are trying to perform the patch, the said shared library has *not been* loaded yet, which explains the message you get.

Run the program to `main`. *Then* you should be able to write to the address. However, you'll need to have write permission on the library to make your write "stick".

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  I ended up needing to write to a different address that was not part of a shared library but this led me to find out where/how I needed to change stuff.  Thanks!